# How can I get PassUrl for a Pass, to open it in Passbook app

Tags: passbook, wallet

It's about Passbook app on IPhone.

My problem is:

- I created passes on server side and allow users to add them into their Passbook via download.
- Now I want to give a link to open a specified pass from web. I known that the link should be in format "shoebox://card/" (this is passUrl of the Pass)

But how to get the  on server side?

Comment: It is possible to do and the format is shoebox://card/{id} where the id is a hash of the pass type identifier and serial number.  This is undocumented and is not supposed to be for public use, but the algorithm can easily be found by decompiling the Wallet binaries.

Comment: "decompiling the Wallet binaries" seems harder than trying to guess the algorithm, especially it is Passbook app from IOS. Can you give me some clues?

Comment: If you don’t already have a working reference ID with a known serial and pass type identifier, it may be close to impossible to ‘guess’ the algorithm.  Decompiling is not as difficult as you may think, but it may breach your Apple Developer agreement.

Comment: I known bot serial number and pass type identifier already. I guess they combine them, then sha1, then base64 encode the digest. But not sure :(

Comment: any proggress please?:)